# Update Content With Ajax in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

OK guys, I'm hopeless when it comes to ajax in wordpress so was hoping you could help me out. I'm trying to retrieve data from twitch and then update it every 5 seconds. The code I'm going to show does work, just not on wordpress as they process ajax differently. Here's my PHP code-

```
<?php

    // setting the options
    $twitch_username = 'ChinchillaDave';
    $twitch_username = strtolower($twitch_username);

    // fetching the twitch stream data | $twitch_stream
    $tsh = curl_init(); // twitch stream handler
    $tsh_url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/$twitch_username";
    curl_setopt($tsh, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($tsh, CURLOPT_URL, $tsh_url);
    curl_setopt($tsh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($tsh, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $tsh_exec = curl_exec($tsh);
    curl_close($tsh);
    $twitch_stream = json_decode($tsh_exec, true);
?>
<?php if($twitch_stream['stream'] !== null) : ?>
    <span class="alignleft">
        <h3><?php echo $twitch_stream['stream']['game'] ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $twitch_stream['stream']['channel']['status'] ?></p> 
    </span>
    <span class="alignright">
        <?php
            $time = strtotime($twitch_stream['stream']['created_at']);
            function stream_started ($time) {
                $time = time() - $time;
                $tokens = array (
                    31536000 => 'year',
                    2592000 => 'month',
                    604800 => 'week',
                    86400 => 'day',
                    3600 => 'hour',
                    60 => 'min',
                    1 => 'sec'
                );
                foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
                    if ($time < $unit) continue;
                    $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
                    return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
                }
            }
        ?>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #4DC47D;"></span><?php echo '<span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Stream Started </span>' . stream_started($time) . ' ago'; ?>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #1a7eda;"></span><?php echo number_format($twitch_stream['stream']['average_fps']); ?><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> fps</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #cd201f;"></span><?php echo number_format($twitch_stream['stream']['viewers']); ?><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Viewer(s)</span>
    </span>
<?php else : ?>
    <span class="alignright">
        Currently offline, please check back soon.
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and my ajax code-

```
function twitchStreamData($) {
    "use strict";
    $('.twitch-stream-header').load('../wp-content/themes/creativenetwork/includes/twitch-stream-data.php'); // loads the php script that grabs the users details from Twitch
    var updateInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $('.twitch-stream-header').load('../wp-content/themes/creativenetwork/includes/twitch-stream-data.php'); // inserts the data into the DOM element {.twitch-stream-header}
    }, 5 * 1000); // updates the php script every 5 seconds and sends it back to the DOM element
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    twitchStreamData($);
});
```

As I've said, I'm hopeless with this and if you can help me out I may through something your way ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Make sure to use wp_ajax_nopriv because you need to call the ajax function from the front-end
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_retrieve_twitch_data', 'retrieve_twitch_data_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'print_twitch_scripts' );

function retrieve_twitch_data_callback() {
    // The ajax request will arrive here
    // You can now retrieve and print the twitch data
}

function print_twitch_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('twitch-script', plugins_url('/js/twitch_file.js', __FILE__));

    // Print a javascript object on the client called 'ajax_object' with an attribute 'ajax_url'
    //  which contains the URL to the ajax file you need to send a request to
    wp_localize_script('twitch-script', 'ajax_object', 
        array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
```

Note that the above code is written for a Wordpress plugin, so you might need to adjust the path to the javascript file.

Then place the following javascript in the file /js/twitch_file.js :

```
function twitchStreamData($) {
"use strict";
    $('.twitch-stream-header').load(ajax_object.ajax_url, {action: 'retrieve_twitch_data'});
    var updateInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $('.twitch-stream-header').load(ajax_object.ajax_url, {action: 'retrieve_twitch_data'});
    }, 5 * 1000);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    twitchStreamData($);
});
```

How this works is explained here: [wp_ajax_(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29)

Comment: Like this? - var ajax_object = Object.ajax_object(ajax_url);

Comment: Just using ajax_object.ajax_url is enough. Wordpress was so kind to make it a global variable (caused by wp_localize_script), so that's how you access it ;)